# Cardinality of a subset of smooth numbers

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Recall: An $n$-smooth number is an integer whose prime factors are all less than or equal to $n$.

Let $k$ and $N$ two integers with $0\leq k\leq N$. Let's put $H= \{n\in[0,N]\ s.t.\ n\ is\ k-smooth\} $.

Let $A=\{I\subset H\ s.t.\ \forall(n,m)\in I\ \ n\nmid m \}$.

How can I estimate : $\smash{\displaystyle\max_{I\subset A}}\ \lvert I\rvert$ where $\lvert I\rvert$ is the cardinality of the set $I$ ?

Comment: Let $\Psi(N,k)$ be the number of $k$-smooth numbers up to $N$. You always can take $I=H \cap (N/2,N]$, whose size is $\Psi(N,k)-\Psi(N/2,k)$ and is of order $\asymp \Psi(N,k) \log(1+k/\log N)/\log k$ (by standard results on smooth numbers). This gives a lower bound on your $\max |I|$; not sure whether this is the maximal $|I|$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.